Overload using a loop: Now there is no sound after evaluating a Routine
Environment

SuperCollider version: 3.13.0
Operating system: Void Linux
Architecture: i686
Setup: nvim with scnvim
Jack version: 1.9.22

How I messed up:
I used a loop inside a Routine (below) for triggering sounds, and forgot to add a .wait. I immediately stopped the SClang interpreter and waited until everything was done. After a minute, I rebooted.
After the reboot and starting Jack (jackd -d alsa) with SuperCollider, everything worked perfectly. The Routine part plays, but after I stop it, I can no longer make any sounds in the scsynth server even though they figure as functional nodes. After closing Jack, this error message shows:
Jack main caught signal 2
Cannot write socket fd = 18 err = Broken pipe
CheckRes error
Could not write notification
ClientNotify fails name = system notification = 1 val1 = 0 val2 = 0
Released audio card Audio0
audio_reservation_finish

If I start Jack from SuperCollider with s.boot the same happens, but the jack server can't be stopped:
jack_control exit gives --exit, jack_control status gives stopped, but qjackctl shows Jack is running and jackd can't start a new server because 'default' server already active.
Moreover, s.quit can't close the scsynth server either. If I restart sclang by manually stopping+starting, the scsynth server still runs and the problem "restarts": I can play sounds without starting the scsynth (as if the jack and scsynth servers never stopped) and after I stop the Routine, new sounds don't play (for instance, evaluating the Routine again).
This is a SuperCollider problem apparently (?), because when I can't play sounds in SC, Audacity and other programs can play recordings through the Jack server.
Summary: SuperCollider plays fine different synths but can only play a Routine ONCE; after playing the Routine, nothing can be played (not even the Routine once again).
The routine in question (from this SynthDef tutorial)
(
var bpm, beat, tatum, map;
s = Server.default;
bpm = 130;
beat = 60 / bpm;
tatum = beat / 4;

map = Dictionary[
  $k -> \kick, // kick is a synth!
];

Routine({
  loop {
    "kkkkkk".do { |character|
      if(character == $.) {
        tatum.wait;
        } {
          if(map[character].notNil) {
            s.bind { Synth(map[character]); 
            tatum.wait;
          };
        };
      };
    };
  };
}).play;
)

I've tried:

Reinitializing both the jack and scsynth servers.
Reinitializing sclang.
Reinstalling the jack package.
Reinstalling the supercollider package.
Rebooting (more times than I'm willing to accept).

None of this things solved the problem.
At this moment I'm just hoping I didn't break my computer, somehow!
PD: In the situation where I start scsynth first, there are no error messages in the SuperCollider post window".
Edit 24/06/2024
As I stated before, if I start the Jack server before the scsynth, it executes the Routine normally once and then fails for the second time. Today, I tried a Jack verbose while running sequentially s.boot and s.quit. The first time everything was normal, but the second time the server couldn't start and Jack would immediately stop. This is the full Jack log:
Jack: JackPosixThread::StartImp : create non RT thread
Jack: JackPosixThread::ThreadHandler : start
Jack: JackDriver::Open capture_driver_name = hw:0
Jack: JackDriver::Open playback_driver_name = hw:0
Jack: Check protocol client = 9 server = 9
Jack: JackEngine::ClientInternalOpen: name = system
Jack: JackEngine::AllocateRefNum ref = 0
Jack: JackLinuxFutex::Allocate name = jack_sem.1000_default_system val = 0
Jack: JackEngine::NotifyAddClient: name = system
Jack: JackGraphManager::SetBufferSize size = 1024
Jack: JackConnectionManager::DirectConnect first: ref1 = 0 ref2 = 0
Jack: JackGraphManager::ConnectRefNum cur_index = 0 ref1 = 0 ref2 = 0
Jack: JackDriver::SetupDriverSync driver sem in flush mode
audio_reservation_init
Acquire audio card Audio0
creating alsa driver ... hw:0|hw:0|1024|2|48000|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
configuring for 48000Hz, period = 1024 frames (21.3 ms), buffer = 2 periods
ALSA: final selected sample format for capture: 32bit integer little-endian
ALSA: use 2 periods for capture
ALSA: final selected sample format for playback: 16bit little-endian
ALSA: use 2 periods for playback
Jack: JackPosixThread::StartImp : create non RT thread
Jack: JackSocketServerChannel::Open
Jack: JackServerSocket::Bind : addr.sun_path /dev/shm/jack_default_1000_0
Jack: JackSocketServerChannel::BuildPoolTable size = 1
Jack: JackEngine::Open
Jack: JackClientSocket::Connect : addr.sun_path /dev/shm/jack_default_1000_0
Jack: JackEngine::ClientInternalOpen: name = freewheel
Jack: JackEngine::AllocateRefNum ref = 1
Jack: JackLinuxFutex::Allocate name = jack_sem.1000_default_freewheel val = 0
Jack: JackEngine::NotifyAddClient: name = freewheel
Jack: JackDriver::ClientNotify ref = 1 driver = system name = freewheel notify = 0
Jack: JackDriver::ClientNotify ref = 0 driver = freewheel name = system notify = 0
Jack: JackConnectionManager::DirectConnect first: ref1 = 1 ref2 = 1
Jack: JackGraphManager::ConnectRefNum cur_index = 0 ref1 = 1 ref2 = 1
Jack: JackDriver::SetupDriverSync driver sem in flush mode
Jack: JackGraphManager::SetBufferSize size = 1024
Jack: JackAlsaDriver::Attach fBufferSize 1024 fSampleRate 48000
Jack: JackEngine::PortRegister ref = 0 name = system:capture_1 type = 32 bit float mono audio flags = 22 buffer_size = 1024
Jack: JackGraphManager::AllocatePortAux port_index = 1 name = system:capture_1 type = 32 bit float mono audio
Jack: JackConnectionManager::AddOutputPort ref = 0 port = 1
Jack: JackEngine::ClientNotify: no callback for notification = 9
Jack: JackEngine::ClientNotify: no callback for notification = 9
Jack: JackAlsaDriver::Attach fCapturePortList[i] 1 
Jack: JackEngine::PortRegister ref = 0 name = system:capture_2 type = 32 bit float mono audio flags = 22 buffer_size = 1024
Jack: JackGraphManager::AllocatePortAux port_index = 2 name = system:capture_2 type = 32 bit float mono audio
Jack: JackConnectionManager::AddOutputPort ref = 0 port = 2
Jack: JackEngine::ClientNotify: no callback for notification = 9
Jack: JackEngine::ClientNotify: no callback for notification = 9
Jack: JackAlsaDriver::Attach fCapturePortList[i] 2 
Jack: JackEngine::PortRegister ref = 0 name = system:playback_1 type = 32 bit float mono audio flags = 21 buffer_size = 1024
Jack: JackGraphManager::AllocatePortAux port_index = 3 name = system:playback_1 type = 32 bit float mono audio
Jack: JackConnectionManager::AddInputPort ref = 0 port = 3
Jack: JackEngine::ClientNotify: no callback for notification = 9
Jack: JackEngine::ClientNotify: no callback for notification = 9
Jack: JackAlsaDriver::Attach fPlaybackPortList[i] 3 
Jack: JackEngine::PortRegister ref = 0 name = system:playback_2 type = 32 bit float mono audio flags = 21 buffer_size = 1024
Jack: JackGraphManager::AllocatePortAux port_index = 4 name = system:playback_2 type = 32 bit float mono audio
Jack: JackConnectionManager::AddInputPort ref = 0 port = 4
Jack: JackEngine::ClientNotify: no callback for notification = 9
Jack: JackEngine::ClientNotify: no callback for notification = 9
Jack: JackAlsaDriver::Attach fPlaybackPortList[i] 4 
Jack: Clock source : system clock via clock_gettime
Jack: JackServer::Start
Jack: JackThreadedDriver::Start
Jack: JackPosixThread::StartImp : create non RT thread
Jack: JackPosixThread::ThreadHandler : start
Jack: JackThreadedDriver::Init real-time
Jack: JackPosixThread::AcquireRealTimeImp priority = 10
Jack: JackPosixThread::StartImp : create non RT thread
Jack: JackPosixThread::ThreadHandler : start
Jack: JackSocketServerChannel::ClientCreate socket
Jack: JackSocketServerChannel::BuildPoolTable size = 2
Jack: JackSocketServerChannel::BuildPoolTable fSocketTable i = 1 fd = 15
Jack: JackRequest::Notification
Jack: JackDriver::ClientNotify ref = 1 driver = freewheel name = freewheel notify = 18
Jack: JackDriver::ClientNotify ref = 1 driver = freewheel name = freewheel notify = 18
Jack: JackDriver::ClientNotify ref = 1 driver = freewheel name = freewheel notify = 18
Jack: JackDriver::ClientNotify ref = 1 driver = freewheel name = freewheel notify = 18
Jack: JackEngine::ClientNotify: no callback for notification = 4
Jack: JackEngine::ClientNotify: no callback for notification = 4

---- S.BOOT IS EVALUATED: JACK DIES ----

Jack: JackSocketServerChannel::ClientCreate socket
Jack: JackSocketServerChannel::BuildPoolTable size = 3
Jack: JackSocketServerChannel::BuildPoolTable fSocketTable i = 1 fd = 15
Jack: JackSocketServerChannel::BuildPoolTable fSocketTable i = 2 fd = 16
Jack: JackSocketServerChannel::Execute : poll client error err = Success
Jack: JackSocketServerChannel::ClientKill ref = -1 fd = 16
Jack: Client was not opened : probably correspond to server_check
Jack: JackClientSocket::Close
Jack: JackSocketServerChannel::BuildPoolTable size = 2
Jack: JackSocketServerChannel::BuildPoolTable fSocketTable i = 1 fd = 15
Jack: JackSocketServerChannel::ClientCreate socket
Jack: JackSocketServerChannel::BuildPoolTable size = 3
Jack: JackSocketServerChannel::BuildPoolTable fSocketTable i = 1 fd = 15
Jack: JackSocketServerChannel::BuildPoolTable fSocketTable i = 2 fd = 16
Jack: JackRequest::ClientCheck
Jack: Check protocol client = 9 server = 9
Jack: JackRequest::ClientOpen
Segmentation fault

And in SuperCollider:
Booting server 'localhost' on address 127.0.0.1:57110.
Found 4 LADSPA plugins
Cannot read socket fd = 8 err = No such file or directory
CheckRes error
Could not read result type = 23
Cannot open SuperCollider client
JackShmReadWritePtr1::~JackShmReadWritePtr1 - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
terminate called without an active exception
could not initialize audio.
Server 'localhost' exited with exit code 0.

Edit 03/07/2024
I made two videos showing the issue:
Example 1: Sound before but not after playing the Routine. Jack error messages.
Example 2: Starting jack from SC breaks it. No sound from SC but Audacity can play audio through the server [This video was recorded after Example 1, so after executing the Routine].

If I am understanding you correctly:

You ran that Routine, but forgot line 20, which has the wait.
It borked audio on your system.
Rebooting your computer has not cleared the issue

If this persists across reboots and you have installed supercollider via apt-get, then something must be wrong with your user support directory, ~/.local/share/SuperCollider. Try renaming or moving that directory.
Start scsynth from the command line. Does it work? Does it work from the IDE? Does it work from nvim?
If it does work, start putting the subdirectories back one at a time to see which one has the problem.
If it doesn't work, then you might try creating a temporary user account on your computer to see if that new user can use SuperCollider.  If it can, then it's still something wrong in your account. If it works from the command line but not from nvim, then the problem is an nvim config file. --> Please reply to name the culprit or if you can't find the problem!
If it can't then this might be a coincidence. Try uninstalling and reinstalling SuperCollider. Or this might be a sign that it's time to go to pipewire.

Hello, thank you for your answer. That's exactly what happened.
Running the scsynth by itself works in the CLI, IDE and nvim. It just doesn't work after executing the Routine. I tried moving the folder anyways and SuperCollider created a new one; the problem wasn't solved. I also created a new user as suggested, but it has the same problem.
I have recorded some videos showing the issue, and linked them in the edit.

So everything is fine after a reboot until you run the routine?

Yes, it breaks only after the Routine is executed, as shown in the videos. Rebooting, reinstalling jack/supercollider doesn't solve the issue (this wasn't happening before the .wait incident, so I don't think is a coincidence [??] :/).

Can you include the SynthDef? I think it's possibly the problem.
